# How to get a static set of pre-specified results with a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I need to create a single column table within a select statement. So, if I do

`SELECT 'a' AS [column]`

I get the following result;

```
| column |
|--------|
|   a    |
|        |
```

But I need a statement which will give me a result as follows;

```
| column |
|--------|
|   a    |
|   b    |
|   c    |
|   d    |
|        |
```

Is there anything I could do to get this result in SQL Server?

Thank you for any help in advance :-)

Comment: You need to reword your question. You're not trying to create a table, you're just trying to get the results in a certain format. Also, is the alphabet literally what you're trying to use as data, or was that just what you chose to use for your example output?

Comment: I am trying to do it for a reason. In this particular application I need it that way and I don't want to create a table for this and mess up my database.

Comment: select `columns` into `newtable` from `table` where `conditions`

Comment: If you're just selecting static values then why do you need to get them from a database?  Can't you just create those values in the application?  It's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mithilatw You never actually answered my question. And arbitrarily deciding not to create a table (if creating a table is the correct solution) does not make any sense. Please edit your question to make it clearer what you're trying to accomplish, and address the questions we're asking of you.

Comment: Okay.. here is what I want.. I have a query producing results in a order which can't be ordered by `ORDER BY` clause. Because the column has ints like 150, 300, 600, and it also has 300 / 600 , 900 / 1500 etc which are varchars. Because of that, even a left padding function don't work in sorting. Therefore I want to create a list of elements and `OUTER JOIN` the results to put it in anticipated order. The result always has set number or rows.

Comment: @mason - did I answer your question in my above comment? And to add to that, The results are presented in an excel sheet direct from a data source connection and there is no involvement in any other programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's what exactly you want then you can use `UNION ALL` like below.

```
SELECT 'a' AS column
UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' AS column
UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' AS column
UNION ALL
SELECT 'd' AS column
UNION ALL
SELECT 'e' AS column
```

Sidenote: `column` is a keyword/reserve word. So either use a different name (OR) escape it using `[]`

Comment: Brilliant idea mate.. thanks for that.. but if I do it this way.. OMG, I need 37 rows in this way. Please refer to my latest comment on the question..

Comment: @mithilatw, Yep already seen your last comment but yes you will have to write all of the. (OR) use some scripting language to automate them and create a SQL script.

Comment: I am so grateful to you @Rahul for actually giving me some constructive feedback and support without thrashing negatives at it without appreciating the diversity of application contexts.

Comment: @mithilatw, You are welcome. Going by your question; your question is properly constructed but the `title` is bit confusing. It would be better for future readers if you could edit the title to something more suitable.

Comment: @mithilatw No one is "thrashing it". You have to make sure you provide enough details in your question that people can answer it. While I have no doubt that Rahul's answer can be used to solve your problem, I do not think it's the best solution, but it would be difficult for Rahul or me or anyone else to give you that best solution without having all the details properly outlined in your question.